# Save asserted facts in file as clause

Tags: prolog

I have a program where i assert some fact. For example:

```
apple(red)
dog(browm)
desk(black)
```

I would like to create a clause in a file. For example:

```
  mylife(my):- 
      apple(red),
      dog(browm),
      desk(black).
```

How can i do to write the fact in a file txt?

Answer (score 2):

easier should be
`?- tell(a_file), listing(mylife), told.`

Also `format('~q.~n', [T])` (or `writeq(T)`), could help.

Of course IO details will be much different depending on your actual needs. If your db is large, and you're using SWI-prolog, look into [QLF](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=qlf) format. It's much faster on loading...

Note that tell/told are a simple tool, error prone, in 'production' code you should `open(a_file, write, S), ..., close(S).` with error handling (see [setup_call_cleanup](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setup_call_cleanup/3)/3)

Comment: In my program i assert some facts. So if i use 'listing(mylife)', it doesn't work because there isn't a clause with 'mylife' as head of clause.